# How to call/use @AndroidEntryPoint annotated class of different module/lib from non hilt module

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I need to use a custom view in my app from an in-house lib. That custom view is @AndroidEntryPoint annotated. In my app Hilt is not enabled.
When I am adding my the view, app is crashing.

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: class com.x.android.y.z.ui.customview, Hilt view must be attached to an @AndroidEntryPoint Fragment or Activity.`

Comment: I think you are missing the @AndroidEntryPoint on the fragment or activity where you USE the view.

Comment: @TheLibrarian in my app, Hilt is not enabled. Is there a way to use the custom view without enabling the Hilt in my app.

Comment: No. That view is relying on Hilt to be present, without it there is no view.